# Why is Neumann boundary condition in linear elasticity prescribed as traction?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, boundary-value-problem, linear-pde

Normally, when you look at what a Neumann BC is, you get that it's a prescribed derivative of the solution in the direction of the outward surface normal at the boundary. However, in linear elasticity model, the Neumann boundary condition is prescribing traction force.

"Standard": $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = a(x) \text{  for  } x\in \Gamma \subset \partial\Omega$$

with $\Omega$ being the domain, $x$ the coordinate vector, $u$ our unknown field (displacement or whatever), $n$ the outer surface normal at given point and $a$ a given function of $x$.

Elasticity: $$\sigma n = t(x)\text{  for  } x\in \Gamma \subset\partial\Omega $$

with $\sigma$ being the stress tensor, $n$ the normal as before, and $t$ some prescribed surface traction.

Now, I do realise that stress is related to strain and that is related to the derivative of $u$, so I guess those two versions are probably closely related. But I struggle to realise exactly how. Are they identical? Is one stronger than the other?

The only thing I could find on this was this post: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29246/traction-stress-stress-displacement-gradient

which shows that yes, if you prescribe the BC in the traction "version", it matches naturally with the boundary integral you get after applying the Green's identity. However, for me the question still remains why cannot I define it as the derivative of the displacement field? What is the fundamental difference?

Comment: Is $\boldsymbol \sigma$ the Cauchy stress tensor?

Comment: @K.defaoite yes

Comment: The two conditions are nearly identical. Recall that $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol u}{\partial \boldsymbol n}$ is actually $(\nabla\boldsymbol u)\cdot \boldsymbol n$. The Cauchy stress tensor $\boldsymbol \sigma$ is written in terms of $\nabla\boldsymbol u$ so you will get terms like $(\nabla\boldsymbol u)\cdot \boldsymbol n$ in that case as well.

Comment: @K.defaoite yes, it is similar, but I am not sure about the details. $\sigma = C \epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ being strain, which then $\epsilon = \nabla u + (\nabla u)^T$. So there is some 4th order tensor in between, but okay, let's say that's just multiplication by a constant. But then you get the transpose term $(\nabla u)^T$ in the strain formula. Doesn't that change something?

Comment: What actual equation are you trying to solve? Incompressible N-S equations?

Comment: No, I am simply trying to understand the connection between the two. I am writing down a ground work theory for my thesis (which is about finite element simulations) and I realised that I don't fully understand how the "typical" neumann condition is related to the traction boundary condition in linear elasticity.

Comment: @JiříBlahoš how did your thesis go? Would you mind sharing it with me? I am also currently working on FEM for linear elasticity and I had a similar question than you. The link that you posted mentions that anywhere where a traction force is being applied, should have a Neumann BC (since a free boundary implies 0 traction); nonetheless, if you could share your research that would be great! :)